# Highlight each 10 line number (not the whole line)

Tags: vim

I have one monitor turned sideways, so I have a nice comfortable 100+ lines of code to look at :). However at this size it is sometimes hard to determine how far down I need to jump to get to 'about' where I want to be (hard to determine n for `nj`). How might I highlight each 10th line number (not the whole line, just the characters on the line which signify the line number)?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718849/vim-highlight-every-nth-line) but its answer is not applicable for highlighting just the line numbers.

Comment: There is an alternative solution for our original problem ("hand to determine n for `nj`) which you may find useful: relative line numbering (`:h relative`). There is also a plugin that will take care of switching relative numbering on and off when appropriate. Please read [this post](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2012/relative-line-numbers-in-vim-for-super-fast-movement/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried relative line numbering, but I still prefer regular line numbering 95% of the time, and it is too much hassle (even on a shortcut) to enable it only when I need it. Eyeballing something close is better for me, but I would like a better gauge to eyeball by (hence highlighting every 10th line number).

Comment: If you're not completely opposed to relativenumber, this page has some great tips for making it come on when in normal mode (moving around) and turn off when editing... http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2012/relative-line-numbers-in-vim-for-super-fast-movement/

Comment: Thank you philwills. In fact, that was the post that introduced me to relativenumbers, and taketwo links to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the problem rather than the question:

You could get **crude-but-effective** and put a "line ruler" on the bezel of the monitor.

Comment: I'm breaking out the white-out and ruler! At least this might make an interesting conversations piece, so long as I never decide to change my terminal font size.

Comment: You can print it on paper, tape it in place, and change it if you ever do change your font size.

Answer (score 2):

There's very little in Vim that could be (mis-)used for that: There are *sign* and *fold* columns next to the number column, but their content is linked to the buffer contents, so you'd need extreme hacks to display 10-line markers based on the current line there.

You could create a small vertical scratch buffer that displays the numbers on the left side, though:

```
:topleft 3vnew | setl nonu nornu | call append(0, (map(range(1, winheight(0) - 1), "v:val%10 ? '' : v:val"))) | wincmd w
```

Comment: Thank you Ingo, that is a seriously creative solution! It does have some issues, though , such as loosing sync with the real line numbers for lines that wrap (as does Ecnerwal's solution). I do enjoy learning from the creative use of some new (to me) VIM functions. Thank you!